# Comparing Multiple Shapefiles

Tags: arcmap, shapefile, comparison

I have 4 shapefiles that I need to compare spatially, to highlight inconsistencies between them in ArcGIS. I have used the Feature Compare tool so far, but I'm looking for a faster way to compare the 4 shapefiles to one another (10 comparisons).

I don't need to compare the attribution, fields, table rows, spatial refs - purely the shape.

Comment: Check out the Topology Builder. You will be able to highlight any overlaps/intersections there.

Comment: Comparing shapes is the hard part.

Comment: I dont think there is a fast way. Use topology as commented or Union tool.

Comment: Are the 4 Shapefiles covering basically the same area and are stacked? You may have similar data that changed over time.
Or are the Shapefiles adjacent to each other, only edges that touch need to be compared?